# I can't add a field inside a one2many tree (in a form view). Why?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

I would like to insert a new field in this one2many in `/stock/stock_view.xml`

```
<field name="pack_operation_ids" context="{'default_picking_id': active_id, 'default_location_id': location_id, 'default_location_dest_id': location_dest_id}">
    <tree editable="top">
        <field name="package_id" groups="stock.group_tracking_lot"/>
        <field name="product_id" on_change="product_id_change(product_id, product_uom_id, product_qty)"/>
        <field name="product_uom_id" groups="product.group_uom"/>
        <field name="lot_id" domain="[('product_id','=?', product_id)]" context="{'product_id': product_id}" groups="stock.group_production_lot"/>
        <field name="picking_id" invisible="1"/>
        <field name="owner_id" groups="stock.group_tracking_owner"/>
        <field name="product_qty" attrs="{'required': [('product_id', '!=', False)]}"/>
        <field name="location_id" domain="[('id', 'child_of', parent.location_id)]"/>
        <field name="location_dest_id" domain="[('id', 'child_of', parent.location_dest_id)]"/>
        <field name="result_package_id" groups="stock.group_tracking_lot" context="{'location_id': location_dest_id}"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

I tried with this:

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='Operations']/field[@name='pack_operation_ids']/tree/field[@name=result_package_id]" position="after">
    <field name="label_qty" />
</xpath>
```

but it doesn't work. I get this error:

```
Error details:
Field `label_qty` does not exist
```

I think that's because it does not detect the model of `pack_operation_ids`

My python code

```
class StockPackOperation(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.pack.operation'

    label_qty = fields.Integer(
        string='Label quantity',
        required=True,
        # default=lambda self: self._get_default_qty,
    )
```

I also tried replacing the whole field and it doesn't work well, it duplicates the field outside the notebook and nothing else.

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just try to upgrade the module properly then after you should change the below code in you xml

first you will check with the your created field is success fully created in the database model structure in Odoo.
check this one first then after you should put that field into the view .xml file.

```
<xpath expr="//page[@string='Operations']/field[@name='pack_operation_ids']/tree/field[@name='result_package_id']" position="after">
    <field name="label_qty" />
</xpath>
```

I hope my answer may help you :)

Comment: Thanks man. I had two sintax errors that I didn't realise: 1.- I forgot the quotation marks for 'result_package_id' 2.- I had the xpath node inside another

Comment: For any one following using odoo greater than v9, the `@string='...'` query has been deprecated. Use the page index like `expr="//page[1]/"` . The index starts at 1 not be confused with array zero based type.